# Mobile App with Delphi - FDQuery Update Issue

Tags: android, delphi, mobile, firedac

I'm facing this nagging problem while using Delphi to develop a mobile App.
On a personnal note, although I have been a huge fan of Delphi and while it has been great on desktop/VCL development, its Firemonkey framework needs a lot of work.

I have followed all the tutorials I could find about the creation of simple CRUD but, something is missing or I am missing something. Anyways, using the Visual Live Binding, I have made all the links that are required. So, here's the scenario:

I have a TDFQuery with the following query: 'select * from customers'
This TDFQuery is linked to a BindSource which is linked to my ListView and to all my TEdit components on my form. Now, The ListView is fine, it shows all my customers. If I click on a customer, I'm taken to the form with all its data for editing. So far, so good, I see the data retrieved from the table, I edit the data and click on the 'save' button and.... nothing. The data is not updated on the database's table, although the TDFQuery is in dsEditModes, which is set when I click on a customer - 'DTM.QryClientes.Edit;'.

Here's the code for the 'save' button:

```
 if DTM.QryClientes.State in dsEditModes then
begin
  DTM.QryClientescl_aniversario.Value := DateEditAniversario.Date;
  DTM.QryClientescl_estado.Value      := copy(ComboBoxCliEstado.Items[ComboBoxCliEstado.ItemIndex], 1, 2);
  DTM.QryClientescl_status.Value      := ifthen(SwitchCliStatus.IsChecked, 'A','I');

  DTM.QryClientes.Post;
end;
```

Before anyone asks, as I said before, everything is connected to everything. For each TEdit there's a field in the TDFQuery's field list, linked to each other.

Comment: Have you renamed the fields or they (mistakenly) belong to another dataset object called `QryClientescl_`? Asking because the IDE naming system do not append postfixes like `cl_` to the field names. Or is that some kind of a linked client dataset?

Comment: Hello Victoria. The table fields have that prefix cl_. For each table I use it. For example, a table called users will have their fields starting with us_.

Comment: Just to make clear, these 3 fields are not bound to anything, since I had to deal with them differently.

Comment: You can bind even them, but even your setup should not cause any problem.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, but it seems that the problem is solved. The thing is since each TEdit has its  'Text' property changed, that change doesn't reflect into the bound field through the BindSource. So, all I did was to refresh the TDFQuery before calling the 'Post' method. - 'DTM.QryClientes.Refresh' - That's it. Thank you again.